# NON Static-Front Page

Tags: frontpage

- There is lot of documentation on how to have a static front-page in wordpress.
- I need to have a dynamic front page, in particular a group from buddy press.
  The link is www.domain.com/groups/challenge-6/

Do I need to update the template or there is a plugin I can use?

Answer (score 2):

Note that when in context of WordPress "static" front page does not meant static *literally*. Usually it means page with certain content that stays same, as opposed to index/archive pages primarily filled with multiple posts that move with time.

So whatever dynamic functionality can be added to appropriate template being used for "static" front page just fine.

Answer (score 0):

There's a little trick that might help you. I don't know anything from BuddyPress, so you'll have to adapt the solution as per your need.

WordPress stores the post id of the page which is set as a static front page in an option named 'page_on_front'. Change that option with a value of your choice.

```
//Hook into init or within your function where you get the dynamic page/post
//Assume the page/post you want to set as front page has an ID = 345

//This check is necessary, if it is not set to 'page' then the latest posts will be shown on homepage
if(get_option('show_on_front') == 'page')
    update_option('page_on_front', 345);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It might be better to set the "static" home page using the tools in the WordPress Settings page, and then insert the custom BuddyPress code into the `front-page.php` template file, which would be used for the site's "static" home page.